# Sending E-mail using JSSEProvider and javax.mail.Authenticator

Tags: android, jakarta-mail

For some reason, when I tried sending an e-mail using this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a/2033124#2033124) , I get an email from google saying: *Sign-in attempt prevented... someone wtried signing in from app that does not meet modern security standarts.*
does anybody know what is the reson?
thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [enable less secure apps](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps) or you need to use [OAuth authentication](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/OAuth2).